# Как работать с FLOAT значениями через dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, .net

У меня есть база данных которую я создал в `mysql Workbench`, я пытаюсь работать с базой через приложение на C# через `dataGridView`. При попытке редактировать некоторые таблицы базы через `dataGridView` я получаю ошибку
`"Нарушение параллелизма: команда UpdateCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей"`
Как я выяснил, тк в самой базе в `Workbench'e` значения `FLOAT` пишутся с точкой как `"0.1"` а в `dataGridView` эти же значения `FLOAT` пишутся с запятой как `"0,1"` из-за этого при попытке редактировать строки с такими `FLOAT` значениями возникает конфликт между базой и самим `dataGridView`.
То есть например: Есть таблица `table1` и в ней поле `field1` и это поле - `FLOAT`, если я хочу там написать `0.1` то делаю это через точку, а если я хочу работать с этим полем через `dataGridView` то я должен делать запись `0,1` с запятой вместо точки. Если запись в строке уже добавлена через `Workbench` и эта запись - FLOAT через точку, то когда я попытаюсь сделать `update` через `dataGridView` я получу ошибку.
Я хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы `dataGridView` принимал вместо запятых точки во `FLOAT` полях, чтобы не возникало конфликта между записью в базе и в `dataGridView`

Comment: Конфликт точно не из-за этого

Comment: Я несколько раз проверил, ошибка возникает только в строках где есть редактируемые FLOAT поля, если их убрать, ошибки не будет

Answer (score 0):

```
var culture= CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator=".";
dataGridView.Columns["field1"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = culture;
dataGridView.Columns["field1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"; //если надо два знака после запятой: 1234567.89
```